# Using C# to invoke powershell server commandlets to Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature netfx3

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am working on a WiX installer that uses Burn and therefore has a .Net requirement.  Bundling the prerequisite version of .Net does not work on server OS's as they require the role manager to be used.  The fact that it's part of a WiX install is not really of overwhelming importance it's there in case there are other methods to help me accomplish my task.  I am running/testing the code below as a standalone .Net Console application.  After failing using [this method](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-Prerequisites-on-Windows-2012-Server-and-the-Server-Manager-requirement-tt7583243.html#a7583449) in order to work around this I wrote the following use powershell and "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature".

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

        Command addDotNet = new Command("Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature");
        addDotNet.Parameters.Add("-FeatureName netfx3 -Online -All");
        pipeline.Commands.Add(addDotNet);
        Collection<PSObject> log = pipeline.Invoke();
```

}

When I run it this window pops up.
*Windows Server roles and features cannot be automatically installed or uninstalled via the Windows Features Control Panel.*
[image]

Seeing as how I figured I was already using the equivalent of "Server Manager cmdlets" I'm not sure what it's actually asking for.  So the two part question is 1) What is the proper way to work around this issue.  2)How do I keep it quiet during install.

PS: If this question really belongs to Server Fault let me know.

Comment: @zespri A program from the [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) toolchain.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers is correct, sorry I didn't make that clear zespri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some additional logging/writeline statements while trying to figure out where things were broken in the server 2012 instance.   I realized that those debug lines were not output to the console at all.

It turns out that I was not READING the pop-up closely enough.  The complaint was not about using the PS commandlets, but a complaint about trying to install .Net 3.5 to run my app.  My app was targeting .Net 3.5 so the message was about the attempt to automatically install .Net 3.5

May this question be more than a testament to my momentary blindness and stupidity, but also serve as commentary on the importance of paying attention to detail and reading the error understanding why it's occurring.  :)

Answer (score 1):

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` is part of the DISM, it would be used to create a windows image to deploy to a new system

`Add-WindowsFeature` is the one you are looking for, it adds a feature to the current instance of Windows Server. It is in the `ServerManager` powershell module, which is only available on Windows Server (not on Windows 7)

Comment: Thanks Eris.  Trying to verify this led me down the road of making sure that ServerManager was loaded which made me notice what finally got me to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All I'm going to say is based on common sense, rather than on prior experience, so sorry if this is not relevant.

You seem to be able to be on Windows Server 2012 as only this version has Windows ADK that you are using. Windows 8 (client os )nd Windows Server 2012 (server os) have differen ways of enabling feature. Those surfaced as Optional Features in Windows 8 but as Server Roles/Features in the server.

Note, that contrary to what you say, the bundle does not work not because it's a server OS it does not work because it's included with the OS and need to be enabled. This applies both to server OS (Win 2012) and client OS (Windows 8).

It's just that you need to use different methods for Windows 8 and Win 2012.

For Windows 8 your method could work. For Windows 2012 the help you are seeing suggest that you use [Add-WindowsFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662309.aspx) cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the command fails, because the component you need to install is not present in the component store. The administrator needs to insert the install media. Perhaps you could include the respective file(s) with your installer to avoid that manual step, but I've never tried that and it might also pose a licensing problem.

For Server 2012 Microsoft decided to remove the .NET framework 3.5 from the component store by default. It's still present on the install media, just not spooled onto the disk during installation. I wrote a [rant](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/fod.shtml) about this in my blog a while ago.

Comment: I thought that may be the issue, but if I Enable the feature directly from powershell it works fine.
`PS C:\Users\Administrator> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName netfx3 -Online -All

Path           :
Online         : True
Restart Needed : False`

It also works fine using dism.
`C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads>dism.exe /online /norestart /enable-feature /featurename:netfx3 /all

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Image Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Enabling feature(s)
[==================100.0%==============]
The operation completed successfully.`